# Python @dataclass Inheritance of Public Variables without double initialization

Tags: python-3.x, python-dataclasses, data-class

Want to write to variables in one class, then inherit those set variable values in another class without having set the values again.

Below code should print 100, without having to initialize the values again for subclass instance; want to use the originally set values in master class (data handler).

One class manages all income data; Data Handler, then the other classes simple inherit those values. What is the way of handling this flow structure ? Please and Thank you!!

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Datahandler: 


    A : int
    B : int
    C : int
    D : int
    E : int
    F : int     



Datahandler=Datahandler(100,100,50,40,10,1000)    




class Some_Class(Datahandler):       

    pass


print(Some_Class.A)
```

Comment: This isn't what inheritance is for. You are inheriting from an instance, not a class, and that's just broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define an attribute of a class, assign to it in the class definition, not inside any function.

```
class Datahandler: 
    staticmember = 200
```

The `dataclass` class won't help you with that.  It is for defining attributes of class *instances*, not classes.

You can then access the base class member in a derived class, which is what you want to do.

```
class Some_Class(Datahandler):       
    pass

print(Some_Class.staticmember)
```

Also, you should avoid using the same name for a class and an instance of that class.

`Datahandler=Datahandler(100,100,50,40,10,1000)   #Likely problematic`

Edit:  While I answered the question as posted, there are simpler ways to do the same thing without using inheritance, as @juanpa.arrivillaga suggested.

Comment: Thank, but my question was a little different: Want to initialize the values in Datahandler once (that come from a data source); but then use them in Some_Class without having to Initialize again, just inherit them.

Comment: Is the difference just that you only know the values to store in Datahandler at run time, not at compile time?  If so, you can just store the values in Datahandler when they are known:  `Datahandler.staticmember = whatever`.  If the difference is something else, please explain.